# Customize grouping header using SfListView

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, syncfusion

I need the items to be grouped, the grouping will be done from the Catalog property, and then I have to have a custom header with some information that will contain these items, example:

- Total number of items
- Total item price
- header name
  I need to manipulate this information that will appear in the header of each grouping, including font, size, position of each label.

This code appears all the information on the screen, but I can't manipulate the value of each property, they are united and displayed vertically aligned.

```
<syncfusion:SfListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListaCarrinhos}" BackgroundColor="White" AutoFitMode="DynamicHeight" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
                    <syncfusion:SfListView.DataSource>
                      <data:DataSource>
                        <data:DataSource.GroupDescriptors>
                          <data:GroupDescriptor PropertyName="Catalogo" />
                          <data:GroupDescriptor PropertyName="QtdTotal" />
                          <data:GroupDescriptor PropertyName="ValorTotal" />
                        </data:DataSource.GroupDescriptors>
                      </data:DataSource>
                    </syncfusion:SfListView.DataSource>
                    <syncfusion:SfListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <ViewCell.View>
                                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Black">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="15" />
                                                <RowDefinition Height="15" />
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        </Grid>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="label" Text="{Binding Key}" TextColor="White" HeightRequest="30" VerticalOptions="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </ViewCell.View>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </syncfusion:SfListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                    <syncfusion:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell >
                                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="LightGray">
                                    <Grid Margin="1" RowSpacing="0" BackgroundColor="White">

                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="75" />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="62" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Source="{Binding Imagem, Converter={StaticResource Base64ParaImagem}}"
                                               WidthRequest="60"
                                               MinimumWidthRequest="60"
                                               HorizontalOptions="Center">
            
                                        </Image>

                                         <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" TextColor="Gray" Text="{Binding Descricao}" BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="10,2,0,0"/>
```

If I use it that way, no information appears on the screen, but the StackLayout that is defined with the black background increases the size.

```
<syncfusion:SfListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListaCarrinhos}" BackgroundColor="White" AutoFitMode="DynamicHeight" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
                    <syncfusion:SfListView.DataSource>
                      <data:DataSource>
                        <data:DataSource.GroupDescriptors>
                          <data:GroupDescriptor PropertyName="Catalogo" />
                          <data:GroupDescriptor PropertyName="QtdTotal" />
                          <data:GroupDescriptor PropertyName="ValorTotal" />
                        </data:DataSource.GroupDescriptors>
                      </data:DataSource>
                    </syncfusion:SfListView.DataSource>
                    <syncfusion:SfListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <ViewCell.View>
                                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Black">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="15" />
                                                <RowDefinition Height="15" />
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        </Grid>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="label" Text="{Binding Key.Catalogo}" TextColor="White" HeightRequest="30" VerticalOptions="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="label1" Text="{Binding Key.QtdTotal}" TextColor="White" HeightRequest="30" VerticalOptions="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="label2" Text="{Binding Key.ItemCarrinhoModel.ValorTotal}" TextColor="White" HeightRequest="30" VerticalOptions="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </ViewCell.View>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </syncfusion:SfListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                    <syncfusion:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell >
                                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="LightGray">
                                    <Grid Margin="1" RowSpacing="0" BackgroundColor="White">

                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="75" />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="62" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Source="{Binding Imagem, Converter={StaticResource Base64ParaImagem}}"
                                               WidthRequest="60"
                                               MinimumWidthRequest="60"
                                               HorizontalOptions="Center">
            
                                        </Image>
```